# Log4net in WPF desktop application log folder issues

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, log4net, desktop-application

When WPF desktop application installed on system , install folder not have proper permission to create log file . We not want to use event log as we need to register for Event Log event fist . That also making some issue .

How to create file and save log for installed Desktop application ?

Comment: Probably "AppData" folder of each user is what you want. Check `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`.

Comment: @emoacht , this was i checking for https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Util_PatternString.htm and bellow answer helped to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify where the file is stored in the configuration file for log4net that you distribute with your app.  You specify it in your AssemblyAttributes like this:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net_myapp.config")]
```

Then in the config file itself you list the appenders.  Here, is an appender for a log file that uses the Windows TEMP folder (which anybody can write to safely) and prefixes each line with a timestamp, thread ID and log level

```
<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%env{TEMP}/MyApp.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="25MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.fff} [%3thread] %5level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```